# Is there a bug with Math.max() when you use .push()?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the max score in an array of constantly updating values. `(example.push(score));`

I have an initial value of `4` in my array, but when I pass in any value greater than `4` it will return both `4` and the value greater than it.

This is my code.

```
setInterval(function(){

var arr = [4];

var randInt = Math.floor(1 + Math.random() * 9);

arr.push(randInt);

var max = Math.max(...arr);

console.log(max);

}, 100);
```

expected output would be any of the following:
 `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `8`, or `9`

actual output is:
 `4`, `5` or `4`, `6` or  `4`, `7` or `4`, `8` or  `4`, `9`

Comment: Dear @omRay, it's a low quality question, your expectation about your code is far from its actions. think different.

Comment: That code produces your desired output. If you think there is a bug in your code, please post the actual code with the bug. Here's a link with info about how to post a good example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Om Ray, what you have asked for is working fine with your code. Either you are missing some important part to mention here or not sure what your inputs or outputs are. Your code works fine here: https://codepen.io/divy3993/pen/ZEGWQvv

Comment: Are you sure you're not logging the value of arr in the penultimate line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code example above a new instance of the `arr` variable is always created, so that's why it will compare `4` or `n`.
If you want to print the max from `4 to 9` you simply just do the following:

```
const arr = [4];

while(arr.length !== 6){ // your condition could be different

   arr.push(arr[arr.length - 1] + 1);
   console.log(Math.max(...arr));
}
```

If you need further explanation, please write down the whole example and what is the final achievement.